# Formula to compute output of a linear system

Tags: impulse-response

The impulse response is $h(t)=e^{-t}u(t)$  and input signal is $x(t)=1 + \frac{1}{2}cos(400πt)$

I want to find y(t)..

I tried to use $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} h(τ)x(t-τ)dτ$ ,however i know that   $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} h(t-τ)x(τ)dτ$  is equal.
Is this the correct formula? 
I tried to solve it but couldnt find come up to a solution..

u(t) is the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function

Comment: This looks like homework, and if so, please add the homework tag.  Hints:  (i) Since $h(\tau)=0$ for $\tau < 0$ (why?), one of your integrals becomes very simple (so does the other though you may not see it to be so). (ii) Think of linearity and superposition.  (iii) If $x(t)$ does not have a $u(t)$ involved in it (check carefully!), the system is in steady state with no transient response to be concerned about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's correct. Here's the *general* way how you can solve such a problem – in this specific example it would actually be easier to just solve the integral, but that seems indeed like homework you should be doing yourself.

I'll call the step function $\Theta$, that's how we always call it in physics – hope it doesn't confuse, and the convolution
$$
  (f\star g)(a) := \int_{\{(t,t')\colon t+t'=a\}}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\mathrm{d}(t,t')\;f(t)\cdot g(t') = \int_\mathbb{R}\!\mathrm{d}\tau\; f(\tau)\cdot g(t-\tau)
$$
which is just the definition that you use. We know the convolution theorem
$$
  \mathrm{FT}(f\star g)(\omega) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm{FT}(f)(\omega)\cdot\mathrm{FT}(g)(\omega)
$$
(the factor $\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ depends on your definition of the Fourier transform). To apply this to your problem first calculate
$$
  \mathrm{FT}(h)(\omega) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\mathbb{R}\!\mathrm{d}t\; e^{-t}\Theta(t)\cdot e^{-i\omega t}
 = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_0^\infty\!\mathrm{d}t\; e^{-t}\cdot e^{-i\omega t}
$$
since the Heaviside function cancels everthing for $t<0$, then this is
$$
 = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_0^\infty\!\mathrm{d}t\; e^{-(1+i\omega) t}
 = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left.\left[\frac{e^{-(1+i\omega) t}}{-(1+i\omega)}\right]\!\!\right|_{t=0}^{\infty}
 = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\Bigl(\frac{0}1 - \frac{e^0}{-(1+i\omega)}\Bigr)
$$
which is just $=1/(\sqrt{2\pi}\cdot(1+i\omega))$. Meanwhile,
$$
  \mathrm{FT}(x)(\omega) = \mathrm{FT}(\lambda t.1)(\omega) + \tfrac12\mathrm{FT}(\lambda t.\cos(400\pi t))(\omega).
$$
These Fourier transforms only exist in a distributional sense; it is known (can easily be shown by inverse $\mathrm{FT}$) that
$$
  \mathrm{FT}(\lambda t.1) = \sqrt{2\pi}\;\delta
$$
and
$$
  \mathrm{FT}(\cos)(\omega) = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2}\bigl(\delta(\omega-1)+\delta(\omega+1)\bigr).
$$
So we have
$$\begin{aligned}
  \mathrm{FT}(y)(t) =& \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}\bigl(\delta(\omega)+\tfrac14\delta(\omega/400\pi-1)+\tfrac14\delta(\omega/400\pi+1)\bigr)}{\sqrt{2\pi}(1+i\omega)}
  \\=& \frac{\bigl(\delta(\omega)+\tfrac14\delta(\omega/400\pi-1)+\tfrac14\delta(\omega/400\pi+1)\bigr)}{1+i\omega}
\end{aligned}$$
and therefore
$$\begin{aligned}
  y(t) =& \mathrm{IFT}(\ldots)(t)
   = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\mathbb{R}\!\mathrm{d}\omega\; e^{i\omega t}\frac{\bigl(\delta(\omega)+\tfrac14\delta(\omega/400\pi-1)+\tfrac14\delta(\omega/400\pi+1)\bigr)}{1+i\omega}
 \\=& \frac{e^0}{\sqrt{2\pi}\cdot 1} + \frac{e^{-400 i\pi t}}{\sqrt{2\pi}(1+\tfrac1{400\pi}i)} + \frac{e^{400 i\pi t}}{\sqrt{2\pi}(1-\tfrac1{400\pi}i)}
\end{aligned}$$
We could know calculate this as an exact expression of trigonometric functions by writing out the $1\pm\tfrac{i}{400\pi}$ as a polar complex number.

Comment: The system is LTI. Thank you for your time i am studying your answer. As for solving the integral infinity confuses me as input signal is periodic.

Comment: @Parhs: if you just solve the convolution integral directly, there's no real trouble with the infinity since your kernel approaches $0$ exponentially fast for $t\to\infty$, so you can simply put in some large upper bound (say 1000) and already get a result that can't be distinguished from the exact one.   If you do it in my way with Fourier transform, you get these Dirac distributions, but unless you're a mathematician you don't need to worry much about those, either.

Comment: Part of the process of becoming an engineer is not only knowing how to use tools but also to learn which tool is best for the job at hand.  Here we have a system whose frequency response function $H(\omega) = (1+j\omega)^{-1}$, so that the output corresponding to input $\exp(j\omega t)$ is $H(\omega)\exp(j\omega t)$, and we are asked for its response to $1 + \frac{1}{2}\cos(400\pi t)$. By linearity and superposition, the response is $$H(0)\exp(0t) + \frac{\exp(j400\pi t)}{4(1+j400\pi)}+\frac{\exp(-j400\pi t)}{4(1-j400\pi)}$$ with no muss or fuss.